# Mostrar en el Admin Django Fields de distintos modelos

Tags: python, django

Les comento tengo 2 modelos

1 - es el User(AbstractUser)

2 - Profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   user_in_charge = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='users', verbose_name='Ejecutivo a Cargo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   phone_number = models.CharField('Telefono de Contacto', max_length=12, blank=True)
   profile_image = models.ImageField(default='default-avatar.png', upload_to='users/', null=True, blank=True)
   role = models.ForeignKey(Role, verbose_name='Rol', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


   def __str__(self):
       return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

   class Meta:
       ordering = ['id']
```

y en el Admin.py tengo

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline): 
   model = Profile 
   fk_name = 'user' 
   fields = ('role', 'user_in_charge', 'phone_number', )


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
   list_display = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff',)
   list_select_related = True 
   inlines = [ UserProfileInline, ] 
   readonly_fields = [
       'last_login',
       'date_joined',
   ]

   fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Necesito Mostrar en el list_display por ejemplo role que es de Profile en ves de ser de User para que en la tabla del admin se pueda ver con todos los datos posibles

quizás estoy hablando cualquier cosa y no es posible pero necesito sacarme la duda

EDIT:
en el `admin.py` cuando pongo:
`list_display = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff',)`
el tema es que necesito que se vea asi:
`list_display = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'role', 'user_in_charge')`

***pero estos últimos 2 son de otro modelo y no se como poder meterlos dentro de esta vista***

Comment: puedes dar una mejor descripcion de tu idea/problemay y de lo que esperas?

Comment: si, en el admin.py cuando pongo list_display = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff',) el tema es que necesito que se vea asi 

    list_display = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'role', 'user_in_charge''  
pero estos ultimos 2 son de otro modelo y nose como poder meterlos dentro de esta vista)

Comment: agrega eso a tu post

Comment: ahí lo agregue, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde Django3.2+ puede usar el decorador [display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator) para mostrar contenido personalizado:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
        'is_staff', 'role', 'user_in_charge'
    )

    @admin.display(ordering='last_name', description='Role')
    def role(self, obj):
        return obj.profile.role

    @admin.display(ordering='last_name', description='Ejecutivo a Cargo')
    def user_in_charge(self, obj):
        return obj.profile.user_in_charge
```

para versiones anteriores:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'role', 'user_in_charge')

    def role(self, obj):
        return obj.profile.role
    role.short_description = 'Role'
    role.admin_order_field = 'last_name'


    def user_in_charge(self, obj):
        return obj.profile.user_in_charge
    user_in_charge.short_description = 'Ejecutivo a Cargo'
    user_in_charge.admin_order_field = 'last_name'
```